# Js className not working

Tags: javascript

again me I ahve been loking for solution for hours. Well this is my problem
JS: `document.getElementById("wrapper").className += " js";`

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
.... 
</div>
```

I get Error: Cannot read property className of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark here. Your script has to either be in the `<head>` or *after* the div for `document.getElementById` to find that node. I'm gathering from your question that this is not the case for your code.

Comment: That JS code is written in functions.js which is declared in `<head>`

Comment: we need to see the rest of your code then. The code you provided will not create the error you're describing.

Comment: JS at [link](http://webdevelope.eu/js/functions.js)

Comment: Why not just add it to your DOM ready event? `$("#wrapper").addClass("intro").addClass('js');`

Comment: I tried even `$("#wrapper").addClass('js');` and it was not working I tried putting your code it is not working either. Ip ut it right after `$(function() { `

Comment: Solved by myself thanks a lot for help